# How can I use the Html.Action's result?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I call a `Html.Action` in my **Home** view like this:

```
<li>
    @Html.Action("IndexWithParams", "Factor", new {factorsRefId = Model.Id})
</li>
```

And this is the `IndexWithParams` in the `Factor`'s controller:

```
[ActionName("IndexWithParams")]
public PartialViewResult Index(int factorsRefId)
{
    var model = factorRepository.All.Where(c => c.FactorsRefId == factorsRefId);
    int sum = model.Sum(c => c.Total);
    return PartialView("_FactorDetails", model);  
}
```

And in the `_FactorDetails` I have a simple table to show data. Now I want to be able to return the sum of the one column in the `_FactorDetails` to the `Home` view which called the `Html.Action`. How an I do that?

EDIT: I can do this by using `Session` like this:

```
Session["sum"] = sum;
```

But I believe using session is not a good practice. Isn't it any other proper way?

Comment: This sum should be part of the view model passed to your main view. You cannot retrieve any such values from an `Html.Action` call - at least not on the server side.

Comment: Is sum in the model passed to your view?

Comment: you can send with model or tempdata or static variable e.t.c

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev I can do this by using Session like I've shown in my updated question. But is it the correct way to do that?

Comment: Although not a big fan of quick workaround but something like `var aggregateModel = new {details = model, sum = sum};return PartialView("_FactorDetails", aggregateModel);`  Obviously, you will have to change the PartialView _FactorDetails for handling the model with aggregate. Don't use sessions please... it's frowned upon :)

Comment: @DarinDimitrov  I can do this by using Session like I've shown in my updated question. But is it the correct way to do that?

Comment: No, I would recommend against using sessions for this.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov So what is the alternative?

Comment: I already wrote this in my first comment and I prefer not to repeat myself.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov But nothing passed to my main view(Home)! I don't get what's your mean.

Comment: Well that's the problem, you should pass a view model that contains the desired sum as a property. Then in your view you can simply use it as `@Model.MySumProperty`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Well, where should I send a ViewModel??? I call it through Html.Action and send a parameter. How can I return a viewmodel to the main view. Sorry I'm really confused.

Comment: The controller action that has rendered your main view should pass this view model to it. Also why are you saying that nothing gets passed to your main view when you are using the `Model.Id` property in the `Html.Action` call? The same way you have this `Model.Id` you can have a `Model.MySumProperty` that your Home controller action should have calculated.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Well, assume instead of the Model I have a ViewModel that also contains the Sum property. I can access the sum and the ViewModel only in the main view. How can I access the sum in the Factor controller while I use this in my main view?? @Html.Action("IndexWithParams", "Factor", new {factorsRefId = Model.Id})

Comment: You can pass this Sum as an additional parameter: `new {factorsRefId = Model.Id, sum = Model.Sum})`.

Answer (score 1):

Just create another model composed of your extra fields and original model:

```
public class BiggerModel
{
    public YourModelsType Model { get; set; }
    public int Sum { get; set; }
}
```

And in your action return it:

```
var model = new BiggerModel
{ 
    Model = factorRepository.All.Where(c => c.FactorsRefId == factorsRefId),
    Sum = model.Sum(c => c.Total)
};

return PartialView("_FactorDetails", model);
```

Sure you will need to tweak around the usage of the model in your partial view too.